# Multiple ajax request getting undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have read most of the multiple ajax request solution.... i managed to make both request run using an if statement nesting.. My code is

```
$(document).on('click', '.postTitle', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    var request = $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/functions.php?job=single_blog',
            cache: false,
            data: 'id=' + id,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'get'
        });

    var request2 = $.ajax({
            url: 'includes/functions.php?job=blog_comment',
            cache: false,
            data: 'id=' + id,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            type: 'get'
        });

    request.done(function (output) {
        if (output.result === 'success') {
            request.done(function (output2) {
                if (output2.result === 'success') {
                    var single_blog = output.data[0].single_blog;
                    var blog_comment = output2.data[0].blog_comment;
                    $('.blog').empty().append(single_blog);
                    console.log(blog_comment);
                } else {
                console.log('ajax2 failed', 'error2');
                }
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Information request failed', 'error');
        }
    });
    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
        console.log('error');
    });

});
```

when i do console.log on var single_blog, i get values but when i try it on var blog_comment i get undefined.... Where am i missing it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$.when.apply()` , a single `.done()`

```
$.when.apply($, [request, request2])
.done(function(output, output2) {
  // do stuff with responses from `request`, `request2`
  if (output[0].result === "success" 
      && output2[0].result === "success") {
       var single_blog = output.data[0].single_blog;
       var blog_comment = output2.data[0].blog_comment;
       $(".blog").empty().append(single_blog);
       console.log(blog_comment);
  } 
})
.fail(function() {
   console.log("error");
})
```

Comment: `output` and `output2` will be arrays, not objects

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of

```
request.done(function (output2) {
```

it should be

```
request2.done(function (output2) {
```

Answer (score 0):

`request` is for `single_blog` and `request2` is for `blog_comment`.

You made small mistake change to below

```
request.done(function (output) {
                if (output.result === 'success') {
                    request2.done(function (output2) {
                        if (output2.result === 'success') {
                            var single_blog = output.data[0].single_blog;
                            var blog_comment = output2.data[0].blog_comment;
                            $('.blog').empty().append(single_blog);
                    console.log(blog_comment);
                } else {'ajax2 failed', 'error2'}
            })
```